# Use all available memory on iPad

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode

I'm trying to make an app that uses all the available memory on an iPad to intentionally bog it down so I can test a few other things when there is limited memory.

Currently I'm using this code which works, but Xcode stops me short with an error that I can't allocate the region. (Stops me at roughly 1.4/4 GB.)

```
while(1)
{
    void *m = malloc(1024*1024);
    memset(m,0,1024*1024);
}
```

I want to use all the memory I can, and hold onto that memory until I say to stop. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use mmap with MAP_LOCKED

Comment: Actually it depends on your goal. There are minimum two memory managers. First one is user space manager. It allocates memory from OS and then give by chunks at your malloc/mmap requests. Second memory manager is inside kernel. Any memory manager can fail on allocation request. If your goal is to test your application under circumstances when malloc can't allocate more memory for you, then there is no any difference between malloc/mmap with MAP_LOCKED. If your goal is to test how OS is working when your process has a large amount of resident memory - then you should use mmap with MAP_LOCKED.

Comment: I got around to trying this as well as a few things, and it seems I can only use up roughly 1.6GB before iOS ends up clearing it out it seems. Any thoughts?

Thanks for the reply, it pushed me in the right direction!

Comment: And what do you think is incorrect with this behavior? OS will not give you all available memory, because itself needs some memory for working.